# ASP.net MVC 4 Razor Upload Image In Pop-Up Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm a newbie in asp.net mvc 4. I develop a web site with mvc 4 and I want to upload image in pop-up window. In this site, there is a blog. I want to upload 3 4 images per post. But If I use default html file upload control, I post an action for getting image link. If I post an action for getting image link, page loaded again and blog content was gone. Therefore I want to upload Image in pop-up window and this pop-up returns image link to user. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
            int len =file.ContentLength;

            var myData = new byte[len];

            file.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, len);

            var fileId = SaveOrWriteToDb(file.FileName, file.ContentType, ref myData);
            if(fileId > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

    }
```

View(javascript is taken from [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery))

```
<div id="popup">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "File", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =   "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input class="file" type="file" name="file" />
        <input class="file" type="file" name="file2" />
        <input class="file" type="file" name="file3" />
        <input id="ok" type="button" value="OK" />
    }
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#ok").click(function () {
        $.each($('.file'),function(){

           var filename = $(this).val();
           $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '@Html.Action("Index","File")',
              enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
              data: {
                file: filename
              },
              success: function () {
                alert("Data Uploaded:");
                //return image link to user here...
              }
          });
        });
      });
 });
```

Sorry didn't test it, I hope it works :).
It's fast example there are lot of thing you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Will you consider using any of the js upload solutions? Like http://www.plupload.com/example_queuewidget.php or or http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/ ?